# Matplotlib adding letter ticks

Tags: matplotlib, axes

Is there a way to add two ticks (ex. two letters) along with existing ticks (numbers)?
I have:
[image]

but want to add two ticks (letters "a" and "b"). Running the following code deletes the numbers and leaves only letters, however I want to have both.

```
ax.set_xticks((a, b))
ax.set_xticklabels(('$a$', '$b$'), size='xx-large')
```

[image: This is the result:]

Comment: What about querying the tick labels with `ax.get_xticklabels`, modifying the ones you want to replace, and then writing them back with `ax.set_xticklabels`? You can also move certain ticks by doing the same with `get_xticks`/`set_xticks`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to use `annotate` instead of placing ticks.

For example, let's start by approximately reproducing your example plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(2.8, 11, 100)
y = 0.2 * np.exp(-0.05 * x**2) + 0.01

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill_between(x, y, alpha=0.3, label='surface', lw=2,
                edgecolor='orange', facecolor='goldenrod')
ax.plot(x, y, color='darkred', lw=2, label='interpolated polinom')

ax.legend(fancybox=True, shadow=True)
ax.grid(ls=':')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$F[N]$', size=18)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$h[cm]$', size=18)
ax.spines['bottom'].set(linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

We could add the "sub ticks" you want with:

```
labelpad = ax.xaxis.labelpad + 15
for val, letter in [(2.8, 'a'), (11, 'b')]:
    ax.annotate('${}$'.format(letter), xy=(val, 0), xytext=(0, -labelpad),
                xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'), textcoords='offset points',
                ha='center', va='top', size=18)
```

[image]

Comment: what if I wanted to have them in the same line as the other tics, for example to replace them?